# Which eclipse ide shall i use in order to run a maven project?

Tags: eclipse, maven

i'm new to maven projects and i don't know which Eclipse IDE i shall i download.

**I.** In my computer i had already installed in the past an eclipse version with the name:
**c:\users\My Documents\eclipse-SDK-3.7.1-win32\eclipse**
but it didn't support maven so i downloaded the maven plugin.

Now i can create a maven project and i can select an archetype 
for the project.

**II.** But i also downloaded **eclipse-java-juno-SR1-win32** (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers) that had already integrated maven (no need for extra download).

Which one of the previous Eclipse IDEs shall i use?
Is there any difference between the two IDEs
as far as maven projects are concerned?

And which one would you suggest for me to choose?

I would be glad if you could help me :)

Thanks, in advance

Comment: I would try IntelliJ communitiy edition. The maven integration in eclipse is appalling. The integration with IntelliJ is not perfect, but it's light-years away from eclipse.

Comment: What's the difference between Ultimate IntelliJ Edition and Community Edition?

Comment: I don't want to sound like a jerk, but I'm sure you can find that information in the idea website. A *feeling lucky* google "intellij community ultimate" will take you to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any, but set-up may differ between Eclipse versions.

If you use [Eclipse IDE for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/junosr1) or [Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-and-dsl-developers/junosr1) then the download will come with [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/) already installed. The only thing you might be missing are 'connectors' that enable various maven plugins, but m2eclipse will download them for you when required.

If you use anything **except** Eclipse SDK, then you can install via Eclipse Marketplace, using *Help -> Eclipse Marketplace*.

The "Eclipse SDK" download doesn't include Eclipse Marketplace. If you get that download, then you can use *Help -> Install Software*, and paste in the following update site URL:

```
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

I tend to use this last method (i.e. specifying the update site) because this works in all Eclipse variants.

Regardless of how you have installed m2eclipse, you'll be able to work with Maven projects in exactly the same way. That means it's difficult to say what the 'best' version for you would be, without knowing more about the kinds of projects you work on. I get the Eclipse SDK download  (because I develop Eclipse plugins) and install m2eclipse on top. If you are developing for Java EE, then you might get the Java EE download and add m2eclipse on top.

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter which package you download from the Eclipse website, as every Eclipse package is basically the same core with different additional plugins. When you have started your version, use Help -> Eclipse Marketplace. Search for [m2eclipse](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) in the upcoming dialog and install it.

Comment: thanks for replying, i have already integrated the m2eclipse into eclipse but i don't know which one of the different IDEs is the best for creating a maven project.